# Acts_as_taggable_on index too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rails-migrations, acts-as-taggable-on

I am trying to use the acts_as_taggable_gem but I am having issues with the migration.

in the automatically generated ActsAsTaggableOnMigration file I am getting the following error

> Mysql2::Error: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767
>   bytes: CREATE  INDEX
>   'index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context'  ON
>   'taggings' ('taggable_id', 'taggable_type', 'context')

on the line `add_index :taggings, [:taggable_id, :taggable_type, :context]`

I have used the gem on another project successfully in the past. The only difference is this time the database charset is `utf8mb4`, This is a requirement to support emojis.

I have tried reducing the `:limit` (default is 128) on the `:context` to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this issue in two ways:

Changing your storage engine (MySQL) from InnoDB to MyISAM, [MyISAM supports    1000 bytes long prefix for indexing, whereas InnoDB support 767 bytes.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Or by specifying `context` length:

```
add_index :taggings, [:taggable_id, :taggable_type, :context], name: 'by_id_type_context', length: {context: 128}

 # => CREATE INDEX by_id_type_context ON taggings(taggable_id, taggable_type, context(128))
```

*Note: SQLite doesn’t support index length.*

Comment: Try with mentioning the length: `add_index :taggings, [:taggable_id, :taggable_type, :context], name: 'by_id_type_context', length: {context: 50}`

Comment: Try with context length 50

Comment: I tired it with length: {context:128} and it got past that error. Same error further along now, but fixing them the same way. Could you put that as an answer so I can mark it as the answer

Comment: I've marked this as the answer but still had another similar problem later in the migrations that wasn't solved with this but I get the feeling there was another field that needed the length set, so I'm still keeping this as the answer